# け as a contraction of 来い

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions, subsidiary-verbs

I’d like to confirm my theory that 来い at the end of a sentence can be colloquially contracted to け. I met this sentence in a comics:

> 置いてけ。

A meaning “Leave it here!” would be very appropriate there. So I suggest that the copula at the end is an imperative こい as mentioned [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/63131/meaning-of-%E3%81%97%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E9%A0%91%E5%BC%B5%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%93%E3%81%84/63192#63192).

Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be the abbreviated version of "埋け”（いけ）?

Comment: ^ `埋け`？? 「置いて**行**け」→「置いてけ」じゃないの

Comment: そう思ったんですけどどうも埋けらしいのですが・・・。（チェック中)＾＾

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/24119/9831 `The 「い」 in subsidiary verbs such as 「いく」 and 「いる」 is often omitted in informal speech.`　See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30995/9831

Comment: 違いまんな。「行け」の命令形の省略でした^^。

Comment: @Chocolate Oh. I did know about dropping い in いる, but I didn’t know that it happens to いく as well.